# Trying to check a string with startswith

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-re, startswith

I'm trying to use startswith to check if something begins with this symbol '<' and then alphanumerical characters. My code is:

`if (line.startswith("<" + r"w\+")):`

I was expecting that if `line` started with `<inserttexthere>` or `<inserttexthere`  it would output True but it's not working. It's probably something to do with my use of `re` and that I didn't format the check for alphanum characters properly.

Comment: Which part of the documentation for [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) leads you to conclude it works with regular expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you doesn't use regex. `line.startswith("<" + r"w\+")` means check if regex start with string `"<w\\+"` exact value not regex interpretation.

In addition `startswith` doesn't allow regex so you should check it this way:

```
import re

# Edit as @donkopotamus pointed well that match doesn't require '^' at the begining
in_re = re.compile(r'<\w+')

print(bool(in_re.match('<test true')))
print(bool(in_re.match('test false')))
print(bool(in_re.match('test <false 2')))
```

It returns:

```
True
False
False
```

Comment: `re.match` implicitly matches from the beginning of the string, so no `^` required